# How are features ranked in RFECV in scikit learn(sklearn)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I used recursive feature elimination and cross-validated (rfecv) in order to find the best accuracy score for several features I had (m =154).

```
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=logreg, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2),
              scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, y)
```

The rankings (`rfecv.ranking_`) and associated score(`rfecv.grid_scores_`) are confusing to me. As you can see from the top 13 features (ranked in the top 10) their ranks are not base on score. I understand ranking has something to do with how and when the feature was excluded in the cross validation process. But then how is the score related to the ranking? I would expect the highest ranked features to have the highest scores.

```
Features/Ranking/Scores
b       1       0.692642743
a       1       0.606166207
f       1       0.568833672
i       1       0.54935204
l       2       0.607564808
j       3       0.613495238
e       4       0.626374391
l       5       0.581064621
d       6       0.611407556
c       7       0.570921354
h       8       0.570921354
k       9       0.576863707
g       10      0.576863707
```

Comment: You are misinterpreting `grid_scores_` and `ranking_`. They have no correlation whatsoever. The `grid_scores_` are not scores of features.

Comment: What are they scores of? Can you elaborate? What are the rankings of, then? Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: From the documentation : "The cross-validation scores such that grid_scores_[i] corresponds to the CV score of the i-th subset of features." They do not represent score of features. They represent score of estimator when certain features are selected.

Comment: You are confused because the size of `grid_scores_` is same as `ranking_`. Change `step` to more than 1, to see the effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_grid_scores` is not a score for the i-th feature, it is the score the estimator produced when trained with the i-th subset of features.

To understand what that means, remember that Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) works by training the model, evaluating it, then removing the `step` least significant features, and repeating.

So, `_grid_score[-1]` will be the score of the estimator trained on all features.  `_grid_score[-2]` will be the score of the estimator with `step` features removed.  `_grid_score[-3]` will be the score of the estimator with `2*step` features removed.

As such, the grid scores do not reflect the scoring of individual features.  In fact, if step is greater than 1, there will be fewer grid scores than features.

Comment: Great thanks! How do I know which features are in each subset?

Comment: The features are eliminated in the reverse order of ranking.  Unfortunately, you don't know the order in which features were eliminated among the rank-1 features (i.e., the selected features).